# Gitlab : gitlab-http.conf revert back to original

Tags: nginx, ssl, gitlab

I'm trying to create SSL for Gitlab server by following the steps below:

1-Change rb file to indicate the external_url

```
/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb
  
  external_url 'https://10.1.43.111:443/gitlab'
```

2-Define the ssl cert in nginx - gitlab-http.conf
/var/opt/gitlab/nginx/conf#

However, when i run reconfigure command for gitlab -->  **sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure**, the content for gitlab-http.conf revert to the original file.

Did I define the SSL setting correctly? Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

One possible cause I get from the documentation "[Configuration options for the GitLab Linux package  / Specify the external URL at the time of installation](https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/configuration.html#specify-the-external-url-at-the-time-of-installation)"

> As part of package updates, if you have `EXTERNAL_URL` variable set inadvertently, it replaces the existing value in `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb` without any warning.

Check the content of `gitlab.rb` after the reconfigure command: if it changes, that would explain why `gitlab-http.conf` is, in turn, affected.